# Django: get object with empty column

Tags: python, django

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
u = User.objects.filter(name__isnull=True)[0]
```

The default value in MySQL for `name` is `None`. I also tried:

```
u = User.objects.filter(name=None)[0]
```

Neither have returned anything, aka, `IndexError: list index out of range`. How do I get an object with no value set as the name?

Comment: `User.objects.filter(name=None)` this one should work. If you set DEBUG to true in setting.py you can check the sql that django queries to database. It looks like name is just not nullable so it doesn't return anything. Moreover if you had bad query it would throw an exception. Also note that empty is no nulll, If you want the empty column you should use name=""

Comment: @deathangel908 turns out, the default in my Django is `name=""`, even though SQL says `None`. Strange.

Comment: Not sure if you already found a solution to this issue, but you can use `Q` objects. Example `User.objects.filter(Q(name__isnull=True) | Q(name="")).first()` - by doing `first()` you would also not run into the issue of list index out of range. (note: `.first()` only works on django >= 1.6)

Comment: This may have to do with the corresponding model field, and the [`null` and `blank` options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#null). Fiddling with those might let you use `None` in Django instead.

Comment: If the `name=""` is the solution that worked for you, you can put that as an answer, for future readers/Googlers. If you find my suggestion about null and blank do indeed change the filtering behaviour, you could add that to the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Even thought MySQL says the default value is `None`, Django used "" as the default, so I used:

```
User.objects.filter(name="").first()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some key concepts.

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This error is not a error looking in the db, this error is given because you are trying to do something with an index of array which does not exist.

```
a = [1,2,3]
a[0] = 1
a[2] = 2
a[3] = 3
a[4] = IndexError: list index out of range
a[n] = IndexError: list index out of range
```

you can do normaly:

```
u = User.objects.filter(name=None)
```

In the DB if you set Null = True and blank = True (i don't recommend this) in the models you can have 'name=None' and 'name=""'

The problem is you are supposing it must be at least one User with your params, for that you are adding the  [0] to retrieve a user instance instead a queryset.

If you expect to retrieve only and only one item of the query you must use the .get, (normally used searching pk, if more than one item is returned it gives an error)

```
u = User.objects.get(name=None)
```

but, if you know more than one item can exist in your with the filters, (for instance, the name not the pk) and you only care about the first you use the .first method, and later you check if exist.

```
User.objects.filter(name="").first()
```